# Any way to use ng-repeat while? I have an array I need to display, but once it hits a certain element I want it to stop showing the rest of the array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way I can use ng-repeat while? I have an array that holds different types of questions and a page break. Once it hits the page break I want the elements to stop loading and display arrows that go to another page. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Extracts the sub-array in your JavaScript code, and use a basic ng-repeat on the sub-array. That's the controller's job, not the view's.

Comment: like pagination ?

Comment: There are multiple question elements in the array and the page break is also an element. So creating a sub array of everything up until the page break element would be my best bet correct?

Answer (score 0):

[Angularjs documentation on Limit to](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Use this Filter to limit the amount of shown questions and once you want a new page, you filter a start index and end index of the array to show

Answer (score 0):

You could split your array in pages and use the ng-repeat only for one page. Something like this:

In the controler:

```
$scope.pages = [[]];
var j = 0
for(var i in questions){
    if(questions[i]==pageBrake){
        j++;
        pages[j] = [];
        continue;
    }
    pages[j].push(questions[i]);
}
```

In your html

```
<div ng-repeat="question in pages[0]">
   ...
</div>
```